# Saving a file in a Snap (Snapcraft) with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, snapcraft

I am having an issue with creating a new file while my snap is running; example:

1) Snap starts and checks for the `config.json` file at `./config/config.json`

2) If that file is not found (it never is the first time the application runs) it will create it `fs.writeFile('./config/config.json', 'My Data', 'utf8', (err) => {....})`

3) I Then look for that file later to use it.

I am able to run my node app and all works as expected when using `node index.js`

I am also able to run using `snap try prime/ --devmode` and all works.

When running `snap try prime/` I get this error in the syslog

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './config/config.json'`

It is erroring at the point of creation.

Any help with this would be awesome!! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by **NOT** creating and checking for the config files in NodeJS and moving all of that logic to an install hook (https://docs.snapcraft.io/build-snaps/hooks).

So now my Install hook will check for the config file and create it if it's not there, then I allow NodeJS to write to that file later so I can still make all the HTTP requests in NodeJS and not in Bash. Below is my Install hook, don't forget to make it executable.

This file is located at `snap/hooks/install`

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

CONFIG_FILE=$SNAP_COMMON/config.json

if [ ! -f $CONFIG_FILE ]; then
    # File Not Found, Create it
    echo '{}' > $CONFIG_FILE
fi
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: How does this script get called?  What does your snapcraft.yaml file look like?